# How to push an element in array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is an array of strings and I want to convert it in an array of symbols by iterating each string element and converting each string to symbol and push each symbol in to an array named symbols.

```
strings = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]  #array of strings

symbols = [strings.each{ |x| "x".to_sym.push }]  #array of symbols
```

I have written above code and problem is with pushing element.
Please tell me the right way to push element.

Comment: This is not hard but may I ask why? The symbols are just immutable strings...

Comment: Ruby comments don't start with `//`, so those samples wouldn't work. Also, this is one of those questions where a few seconds looking at the documentation for [`push`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-push) would have solved the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Array#map instead:

```
symbols = strings.map { |x| x.to_sym }  # array of symbols
```

Comment: Who voted this down, it is a correct answer voted up

Comment: Indeed, it is. Now. Except for non-ruby comment.

Comment: Ahh yes you are correct about that, Did not notice.

Comment: You can also use the `map` method this way: `strings.map(&:to_sym)` @AshishKumar but only if you are Ruby 1.9.3 or >. (http://m.onkey.org/let-s-start-with-wtf)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need push here, you need `collect`.

```
 symbols = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"].collect{|x| x.to_sym}
```

This will accomplish what you want.

Comment: sorry I didnt see @Michaels answer, I also have the same code and it works. Since you have posted it first you win :D. (I'm taking my answer back)

Answer (score 2):

Like some of posters suggested, you could use `Array#map` for this purpose. As you want simple conversion, you can even use `to_proc` notation for brevity:

```
symbols = array_of_strings.map(&:to_sym)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the block of code that you're looking for:

```
strings = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]  //array of strings
symbols = Array.new

strings.each do |x|
    symbols << x.to_sym
end
```

Comment: Although your solution does what OP asked for, it is not ruby-way of solving this problem.

Comment: @samuil That is true, but note that it is generally accepted that the only reasons to downvote an answer are a) if it does not actually solve the question, or b) if it is a **terrible** coding practice. This answer is not the best way to do it, but I personally do not consider it **terrible**.

Comment: Code is incorrect (due to original comment), and I think it is pretty harmful to a ruby newbie, to approach easy tasks in **bad** way (not terrible, you're right). You may be right, that it doesn't deserve downvote.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
strings.map &:to_sym
```